# Android SQLiteDatabase query sorting order

Tags: android, sqlite

I have data in my database like this:

```
Alice
anderson
Beatrice
benny
Carmen
calzone
```

Using this code:

```
mDb.query(DATABASE_NAMES_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_NAME }, null, null,
            null, null, KEY_NAME+ " ASC");
```

or this code with the filter being "":

```
mDb.query(true, DATABASE_NAMES_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
        KEY_NAME }, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
        new String[] { filter+"%" }, null, null, null,
        null);
```

It sorts the above data like this:

```
Alice
Beatrice
Carmen
anderson
benny
calzone
```

Is this normal behavior? How do I get it to sort to the above order where all the As and Bs and Cs are together? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify case sensitivity by adding `COLLATE NOCASE`, either in your `ORDER BY` clause, or (preferably) when you create the table itself in your declaration of that particular column.

Answer (score 12):

SQL uses ASCII location to sort so you'd use "COLLATE" in some fashion...

Something in the nature of:

```
ORDER BY YourColumn Collate NOCASE
```

or

```
ORDER BY YourColumn Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN
```

Comment: Your answer is correct too but EboMike got to it first. :) Thanks though you were spot on!

Answer (score 1):

Cursor c = db.query(YOUR_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, YOUR_COLOMN_NAME+" Collate NOCASE");

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: in my case, i want to display 'name' from my 'form' table in order, so i used..--> Cursor c = db.query("form", null, null, null, null, null, "name Collate NOCASE");           And then --->    while (c.moveToNext()) {  String studentname = c.getString(0).toString()}     Note;- 'name' is my first colomn in database.